# Docker-Compose cannot locate specified Dockerfile

Tags: docker, nextcloud

I've copied a docker-compose.yml from github with the following:

```
version: '3' 

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:12-alpine
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - nextcloud-db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    env_file:
      - db.env 

  app:
    build: ./nextcloud-cron
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - nextcloud-data:/var/www/html
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=xxx
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=xxx
      - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=xxx
      - POSTGRES_HOST=xxx
      - POSTGRES_DB=xxx
      - NEXTCLOUD_OVERWRITEPROTOCOL=https
      - NEXTCLOUD_ADMIN_USER=xxx
      - NEXTCLOUD_ADMIN_PASSWORD=xxx
   
    env_file:
      - db.env
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - nextcloud-proxy-tier
      - default 

  proxy:
    build: ./proxy
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 7080:80
      - 7443:443
    labels:
      com.github.jrcs.letsencrypt_nginx_proxy_companion.nginx_proxy: "true"
    volumes:
      - nextcloud-proxy-certs:/etc/nginx/certs:ro
      - nextcloud-proxy-vhost.d:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - nextcloud-proxy-html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
    networks:
      - nextcloud-proxy-tier 

  letsencrypt-companion:
    image: jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - nextcloud-proxy-certs:/etc/nginx/certs
      - nextcloud-proxy-vhost.d:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - nextcloud-proxy-html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
    networks:
      - nextcloud-proxy-tier
    depends_on:
      - proxy 

  collabora:
    image: collabora/code
    restart: always
    networks:
      - nextcloud-proxy-tier
    depends_on:
      - proxy
    cap_add:
     - MKNOD
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:9980:9980
    environment:
      # IMPORTANT: Note the backslashs before the dots here (and only here)!
      - domain=xxx
      - username=xxx
      - password=xxx
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=xxx
      - VIRTUAL_NETWORK=nextcloud-proxy-tier
      - VIRTUAL_PORT=9980
      - extra_params=--o:ssl.enable=false --o:ssl.termination=true
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=xxx 

volumes:
  nextcloud-db:
  nextcloud-data:
  nextcloud-proxy-certs:
  nextcloud-proxy-vhost.d:
  nextcloud-proxy-html: 

networks:
  nextcloud-proxy-tier:
```

and everytime I try to run

```
docker-compose build --pull
```

I get this error message:

```
Building app
ERROR: Cannot locate specified Dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

Has anyone a clue what the problem is?!

Thanks

Comment: perhaps you didn't copy the Dockerfile - or the whole `nextcloud-cron` and `proxy` folders from that repository - you need ALL the files from `https://github.com/bentolor/docker-nextcloud-collabora-postgresql-letsencrypt` -

Comment: This question isn't relevant to Raspberry Pi. Nothing about your issue is specific to Raspberry Pis, it's just about Docker, which I assume you are running on an RPi, but your question doesn't even specify that. Try re-asking on SuperUser or something.

Answer (score 0):

You have already answered your Problem

```
ERROR: Cannot locate specified Dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

Composer Pull cannot locate the Dockerfile.

The Question is from where do you run this command? According to the official documentation you have to run the command in your Project dir
[image]

https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/

The Yaml file looks valid so far as i can tell.
[image]
I imagine you are in the wrong directory

Answer (score 0):

As @Phong mentioned, you may be in a different directory than the location of your `Dockerfile` since `docker` can't find it. Another reason could be that your Dockerfile is not named "Dockerfile" and you *are* actually in the right directory.